# twitter bootstrap - multi column dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a twitter bootstrap dropdown that has somewhere between 7-36 menu items.  Unfortunately with that many items, I can only see the first 15 or so. I'd like to be able to split the number of items so that there are no more than 10 per column, before a new column is created.

I'm not trying to do nested dropdowns, I'm just trying to change the presentation of the dropdown so that there are no more than 10 items per column, however all of the items should still be displayed. I tried putting every 10 `li`s into their own div but that's not even HTML compliant I think. Is it possible to do this via TBS?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's `.row-fluid` to accomplish what you need.

I've inlined the css for the width of the dropdown menu but you can specify a class/id and include that in your stylesheet.

Basically, what's going on here is:

- We are creating a fluid grid inside of the dropdown
- Setting a fixed width for the dropdown container itself
- The `li` tags are inheriting their style from the parent dropdown

The example below was only tested in Chrome v23

*** Boostrap 2.x:**

```
<ul id="multicol-menu" class="nav pull-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MultiCol Menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <div class="row-fluid" style="width: 400px;">
                    <ul class="unstyled span4">
                        <li><a href="#">test1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test1-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="unstyled span4">
                        <li><a href="#">test2-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test2-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test2-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="unstyled span4">
                        <li><a href="#">test3-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test3-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test3-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**[EDIT]**

*** Boostrap 3.x:**

```
<ul id="multicol-menu" class="nav pull-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MultiCol Menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <div class="row" style="width: 400px;">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
                        <li><a href="#">test1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test1-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
                        <li><a href="#">test2-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test2-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test2-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
                        <li><a href="#">test3-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test3-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test3-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if someone is looking for a bootstrap 1.4 solution use `class="row container-fluid"` instead of `row-fluid`

Comment: I'm surprised anyone in 2014 would be posting an update for Bootstrap 1.4 as opposed to BS 3+. :)

Comment: Is it just me, or do the columns loose their responsiveness? e.g., try `<ul class='list-unstyled col-md-4 col-xs-12'>`

Comment: On Bootstrap 3, styling was lost on the drop-down columns.

Comment: Great job @inki! But I have a question: How can I to center the div? I want center screen, not starting at the li parent :c or how to make full width, but will be more nice if there's a possible to center it! Thanks!

Comment: Adding the styles `margin:0 auto !important;position:relative;display:block;` to `<ul class="dropdown-menu">` it centers the div but broke the menu :(

Answer (score 53):

I've solved it by adding class "columns" where I've set columns count and drop down width. 
Of course you can set columns count and width depending on media queries.

https://jsfiddle.net/maciej_p/eatv1b4b/18/

HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">wybierz region<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu columns">
        <li><a href="#"><strong>Górny Śląsk</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">powiat będziński</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">powiat bielski</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">powiat bieruńsko-lędziński</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">powiat cieszyński</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">powiat częstochowski</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">powiat gliwicki</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">powiat kłobucki</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">powiat lubliniecki</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">powiat mikołowski</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">powiat myszkowski</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px){
    .columns{
        height: 200px;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px){
    .columns{
        -moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
        -webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
        column-count:2;
        width: 500px;
        height:170px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The above solutions make it hard in a dynamic setting, yours is perfect and much more flexible. Cheers to you sir!

Comment: can we have Variable width for columns? I'm having an issue such that a single item with too much width is causing all the columns in dropdown to resize to width on that item. Thus looking awkward, where column 1 which si single word is taking up half the space of the browser width while second column fits the title text accordingly.

Comment: @VarunC try using column-span 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-span.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-span

Comment: that's the best solution. Small code and work very well. In my case when I added another div (trying the first answer) inside de UL, all my texts change the color, with this solution this not occur. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, it works great - for sure. But has no IE-Support at all. Works only in IE12.

Comment: This is an especially helpful solution when you're creating dropdown menus dynamically (e.g., WordPress) and changing the markup for a dropdown menu is kind of a pain.

Comment: Great for a responsive design!!

Answer (score 13):

I adjusted the code to suit Bootstrap 3. For a 3-column dropdown:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Heading 1 </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu multi-column">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Col 1 - Opt 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Col 1 - Opt 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Col 2 - Opt 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Col 2 - Opt 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Col 2 - Opt 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Col 2 - Opt 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I had to add the min-width, otherwise the 3rd column overflowed the right margin:

```
.dropdown-menu.multi-column {
        width: 400px;
}

.dropdown-menu.multi-column .dropdown-menu {
        display: block !important;
        position: static !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        border: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        min-width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Cool bro! Works nice! Thanx! ;)

Answer (score 5):

Also have a look at the **Mega Menu** offerings out there.

(it helps if you say '**Mega Menu**' in a silly voice)

Once decent offering is [YAMM](http://geedmo.github.io/yamm/) or [YAMM3](http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/) (depending on which version of [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) you are using).

Comment: YAMM worked very well and was very easy to integrate (I used YAMM3 with Bootstrap 3.3.7). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a recent post showing how to achieve this for 2 columns that should be easily modified to fit your needs by changing the width of the multi-column dropdown and changing the number of spans in your fluid row.

Check it out: http://www.devlifeline.com/2013/09/multi-column-bootstrap-dropdown.html

FYI - This keeps the styles consistent with other bootstrap dropdown menus