# Multicolumn Scrollable Bootstrap 3 Menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap 3 website with two dropdowns in the navbar. One of the dropdown sometimes has a few items (as few as 4) and sometimes as many as 150. These are short items - a few characters each.

As a first solution I've created a 3-column dropdown as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19337287/871910) . However, with 150 items on some screens not all the items fit. What I would like to do is add a scrollbar.

[This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227496/scrollable-menu-with-bootstrap-3-menu-expanding-its-container-when-it-should-n) works for single column dropdowns, but not for multi column menus.

Is there a way to add a scrollbar to a multicolumn dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a specific max height (ie: `max-height:200px`) and `overflow-x:hidden` like this..

.scrollable-menu {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

Then apply the `scrollbar-menu class` to your `dropdown-menu`

**Demo:** http://www.bootply.com/5XG5xQDRk0